"Errores en las importaciones de Angular en Visual Studio Code aunque las rutas y dependencias son correctas"
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Angular17 en Visual Studio Code. Las rutas de las importaciones están configuradas correctamente y el proyecto se compila y ejecuta sin errores tanto en el frontend como en el backend. Sin embargo, Visual Studio Code marca las importaciones como si estuvieran erróneas, mostrando mensajes como:
"No se encuentra el módulo ... ni sus declaraciones de tipos correspondientes"


Esto muchas veces se soluciona reiniciando... VS code a veces entiende mal algunas cosas...

@gbianchi He realizado las siguientes acciones y aún así me sigue apareciendo los mensajes de error:
-Verifiqué que las rutas de importación existen y son correctas en la estructura del proyecto.
-Reinstalé todas las dependencias (node_modules) usando npm install.
-Limpié la caché de npm con npm cache clean --force.
-Reinicié TypeScript Server en Visual Studio Code con el comando "TypeScript: Restart TS Server"
-Eliminé la caché del Angular con rm -rf .angular/cache.
-Reinstalé las extensiones de angular que tenía integradas en vscode.

no se si angular lo tiene, pero probaste eliminar el import e ir donde esta la variable y decirle que agregue el import solo?
